# guardar un array en otra variable y acceder a los arreglos php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

quiero guardar todos los datos de mi columna productos de base de datos para después comprarlos con otra base de datos que tengo pero al guardar los datos lo estoy haciendo de la síguete manera y quiero ir accediendo a cada uno de estos para trabajar con ellos lo estoy haciendo de esta manera

```
$Productos_Sucursal_sql = "SELECT * FROM productos_sucursales WHERE sucursal = '$sucursal' ";
                                    $Sucursal_result = mysqli_query($con, $Productos_Sucursal_sql);
                                    while ( $Productos_Sucursal_row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sucursal_result) ) { 
                                    $varaible_cool = $Productos_Sucursal_row['producto'] ;
                                    
                                    }
                                    
                                      echo $varaible_cool[10];
```

pero al imprimir mi variable me devuelve solo una letra cuando quiero ver todas mis variables que contiene este array o también el poder acceder a una en especifico

Answer (score 0):

Debe cambiar

```
mysqli_fetch_array
```

por

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc
```

También puede revisar ésta opción

```
mysqli_fetch_all( $Sucursal_result , MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Para sacar el resultado final, debe crear un array aparte y dentro del while agregarlo con array_push , de lo contrario le devolverá siempre el último resultado de todo el ciclo.

Comment: lo que e hecho fue agragar un `$Productos_Sucursal = array();` antes de while y cambiar `$varaible_cool = $Productos_Sucursal_row['producto'] ;`  por `$Productos_Sucursal[] = $Productos_Sucursal_row['producto'] ;` y ya con un `echo $Productos_Sucursal[0]` accedo al valor en especifico